# Swapping value of array using GridView in Flutter not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating a 3x3 magic square game using Gridview in Flutter. What I have right now is the UI for swapping values using Gridview. Now, I need to click two cells in order to swap the value until it forms a magic square. The problem is once I clicked the second cell to swap the value, the first cell didn't get the correct value but the second get it right. Below is my code. Any help please?

Sample Data

```
import 'package:flutter_app_magicsquare/model/TileModel.dart';

String selectedTileValue="";
late TileModel selectedTile;
int selectedIndex=0 ;
bool selected = true;
int points = 0;


List<TileModel> myPairs=[];

List<TileModel>  getPairs(){

  final items=[
    TileModel(value: "8", isSelected: false),
    TileModel(value: "1", isSelected: false),
    TileModel(value: "6", isSelected: false),
    TileModel(value: "3", isSelected: false),
    TileModel(value: "5", isSelected: false),
    TileModel(value: "7", isSelected: false),
    TileModel(value: "4", isSelected: false),
    TileModel(value: "9", isSelected: false),
    TileModel(value: "2", isSelected: false),
  ];
  return items;
}
```

Model

```
class TileModel{

  String value;
  bool isSelected;

  TileModel({ required this.value, required this.isSelected});

  void setValue(String selectedValue){
    value = selectedValue;
  }

  String getValue(){
    return value;
  }

  void setIsSelected(bool getIsSelected){
    isSelected = getIsSelected;
  }

  bool getIsSelected(){
    return isSelected;
  }
}
```

Main code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_magicsquare/data/data.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_magicsquare/model/TileModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
List<TileModel> gridViewTiles = [];
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  //late TileModel firstTile;
  //late TileModel firstTile;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    myPairs=getPairs();
    myPairs.shuffle();
    gridViewTiles=myPairs;

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 50),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[

              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              GridView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                //physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                    mainAxisSpacing: 0.0, maxCrossAxisExtent: 150.0),
                children: List.generate(gridViewTiles.length, (index) {
                  return Tile(
                    value: gridViewTiles[index].getValue(),
                    tileIndex: index,
                    parent: this,
                  );
                }),
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Tile extends StatefulWidget {
  String value;
  int tileIndex;
  _MyHomePageState parent;

  Tile({ required this.value, required this.tileIndex, required this.parent});

  @override
  _TileState createState() => _TileState();
}

class _TileState extends State<Tile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {

          if (selectedTileValue != "") {
            var secondSelected=gridViewTiles[widget.tileIndex];
            secondSelected.setIsSelected(true);
            setState(() {

              gridViewTiles[widget.tileIndex]=selectedTile;

              gridViewTiles[selectedIndex]=secondSelected;

              selectedTileValue="";
            });


          } else {
            setState(() {
              selectedTileValue=gridViewTiles[widget.tileIndex].getValue();
              selectedTile = gridViewTiles[widget.tileIndex];
              selectedTile.setIsSelected(true);
              selectedIndex = widget.tileIndex;
            });

            setState(() {
              gridViewTiles=myPairs;
            });

          }
       // }
      },
      child: Container(

        color: Colors.blue,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child:Center(
          child:Text(myPairs[widget.tileIndex].getValue()) ,
        )


      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a unique key to the GridView tiles. Flutter may not be detecting that the Tile list is being changed properly. When you update or regenerate your list of tiles, UniqueKey() will give Flutter the information it needs to determine that your list changed.

Within your Tile Widget at the GestureDetector()

```
class _TileState extends State<Tile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      onTap: () {
```

The Flutter team has made many great videos that explain proper use of many Flutter widgets. This one explains [UniqueKey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc&ab_channel=GoogleDevelopers)

Comment: Hi @Curt, still not working.